# is there any way of simulating an autocommit in functions in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I know you can't control transactions in functions or procedures, but I'm wondering if there's something *like that* or some alternative.

The problem:  I have a function that's very expensive that turns things like a customer id into a nice html report.  Trouble is - it takes seconds... so I've put into the function something that basically looks at a cache to see if a pre-rendered one exists, returning it if it does - and if it doesn't - it adds to the cache afterwards - so it will only ever render things once.

Now - given most things will never change - I sort of want to do it across everything - but given the time - it will probably take about 1 year to run - which is ok actually - this system has to run for ten.  Trouble is - I don't want it to lock anything on the database, so I sort of want it trickle along, doing 1 at a time and committing immediately.

I investigated pg_cron, because that seemed an option, but the version of aurora I am using doesn't support it.   Any ideas how I'd do this inside the database?

Answer (score 0):

Add a text column to the customer table to hold the html report.

Put trigger(s) on table(s) whose content influences the html report that refreshes the report column.

This gives you instant retrieval and only (re)calculates it when needed.

---

Or if data is stable:

```
create table customer_report (
  customer_id int not null primary key,
  report text not null
);

insert into customer_report
select id, my_report_proc(id)
from customer;
```

Comment: doesn't work like that - the data _never_ changes - this is an archive system reflecting what happened in a project.   At the moment, when a user goes to look up a customer, it can take 3-4 seconds to compute the report - it goes to a bunch of different tables and does ...work... but if cached, it's ms... so I want to cache... everyone.

Comment: @DarrenOakey how about plan B in answer.

Answer (score 0):

By all means, don't code that as a function running inside the database. It is fine to do the calculations in the database, but generating a report and iterating over customers belong into client code. That way, committing each report is not a problem.

Comment: the problem is it will take like a year to run - and I don't have another machine that will be around that long - in fact _I_ will not be around that long - the only thing I can be sure of is the database

Comment: You can run client code on the database server machine, that is just as robust. You cannot rely on a machine staying up for a year; you will have to teach the software how to survive down time.

Comment: oddly enough no - I don't have a database server either.  The application is in lambda, and the database is aurora [postgres flavoured].  The whole idea is that in 10 years, someone might use it twice a year, so the company only pays for those calls  - so it's quite the opposite - this software is all about the downtime.

Comment: If you plan something that will be around for a long time, you have to provide some continuity. Consider writing documentation.